# Syncing folders using bash script without rsync

Tags: bash, synchronization, scp

I have been tasked with performing backups of a VMware vCenter appliance database. We were unable to install the Backup Exec agent for Linux so we are dumping the database to disk and then using a script SCP'ing them over to another *nix box.

This is working fine, and I have it so on the appliance we only keep a weeks worth of backups.

The issue I am having is making sure the backups on the remote machine are in sync so there is only the weeks worth on both machines.

Rsync isn't installed, so I have no idea how to handle deleting them remotely without setting up another script on the remote machine which I'd rather not do.

Any way this can all be accomplished in the one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `scp`, you can probably use `ssh` as well to execute remote commands.

Try:

```
ssh user@remote find /some/folder/with/backups -mtime +7 -type f -print
```

When it works, replace `-print` with `-delete` (or `-exec rm "{}" \;` if `-delete` isn't supported).

Comment: Whist this isn't working 100% (I can only ever get it to list all files) it certainly seems it is what I want... Thanks! Will keep digging away until I get it working :)

Comment: Yes I read that.... What I mean is that it only lists all files, not files that are more than (for testing at this stage) 2 days old. +7 lists nothing as does +2

Comment: After reading the documentation, `+7` should give you the files older than 7 days. `-print` should show you the date of the file. Are there any in the list which are less than 7 days old? Note: You can get a sorted list of files with `ls -lrt` (long listing, reverse order, by time)

Comment: I see the problem now thanks to the `ls -lrt` command. All my files were transferred on the same day (first time) so I will monitor this and check it over the next few days! Thanks.

Comment: Try `scp -p` to "preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file."

Comment: ...and now it doesn't like `-delete` at the end of the find command :(

Comment: Some old versions of `find` don't support `-delete`. Use `-exec rm "{}" \;` instead.

Comment: for completeness, that didn't work for me I had to use `-exec rm "{}" +` making the full command: `ssh username@SERVER find /backups/ -mtime +8 -type f -exec rm {} +` - now fully working! :D

Comment: Yes, when doing a remote call, you'd probably need \\\; or even more \'s